# Javascript: String representation of a Date object is one month "later" than the actual value?

Tags: javascript, date

This is what I see in a chrome console:

```
> new Date(2012, 9, 13).toString()
"Sat Oct 13 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (CST)"
> new Date(2012, 9, 13).getMonth()
9
```

Apparently it should be `Thu Sep`.. What did I miss??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `month` is form `0` ~ `11`, **zero-indexed**.

**month**

> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to
>   11 for December.

Comment: This is really unexpected.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why but the Date constructor is specified to have Jan = 0, ... Dec = 11.  You are actually creating an October date, and it's printing out correctly.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Not just the constructor, this applies to methods that get and set the month as a number.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MDN documentation for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> `month`
>
> Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
>   January to 11 for December.

Answer (score 0):

The ECMAScript [specification for the Date object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.4) notes that the month is 0-indexed (much like in Java), so `9` represents October:

> **15.9.1.4 Month Number**
>
> A month value of 0 specifies January; 1 specifies February; 2 specifies March; 3 specifies April; 4 specifies May; 5 specifies June; 6 specifies July; 7 specifies August; 8 specifies September; 9 specifies October; 10 specifies November; and 11 specifies December. Note that MonthFromTime(0) = 0, corresponding to Thursday, 01 January, 1970.